# Formula adding and removing classes JS

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to make a formula that adds or removes classes from DOM.

const short is just an example of what I am struggling with. In the code you can meet this error with

```
export const hideNonIlluminated

import myDOMelement from './dom-element.js';
import { short, long, all, LMDChoice, LMSChoice, LMSMChoice, hideNonIlluminated, hideIlluminated, powerLEDClass, normalLEDClass } from './utility-variables.js';
```

```
export const short = [
    {
        elementId: "short-sides",
        action: "add",
        className: "active"
    },
    {
        elementId: "long-sides",
        action: "remove",
        className: "active"
    },
    {
        elementId: "all-sides",
        action: "remove",
        className: "active"
    },
];
```

I believe that there is some kind of reference problem in import/export...

```
const addRemoveClasses = element => {
    element.forEach(({ elementId, className, action }) => myDOMelement[elementId].classList[action](className));

};
```

```
myDOMelement['short-sides'].addEventListener("click", () => addRemoveClasses(short));
```

How shall I make it work?

myDOMelement looks like this:

```
const x = ['height', 'width', 'single-sided', 'double-sided', 'wp', 'print-price', 'power-led', 'normal-led', 'support', 'support-choice', 'long-sides', 'short-sides', 'all-sides', 'choice-with-print', 'choice-without-print', 'illuminated', 'non-illuminated', 'LMD', 'LMS', 'LMSM', 'DTF', 'STF', 'STFL'];

const funGetX = () => {
    return x.reduce((acc, classX) => {
        acc[classX] = document.getElementById(classX);
        return acc;
    }, {});
}

const myDOMelement = funGetX();

export default myDOMelement;
```

here is the github repo: https://github.com/kapek/adsystem.git

```
script.js:127 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList')
at script.js:127:38
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at addRemoveClasses (script.js:123:10)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (script.js:216:61)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    const addRemoveClasses = element => {
    element.forEach(({ elementId, className, action }) => myDOMelement[elementId].classList[action](className));

};
```

My code works just fine. The reason I was getting an error is because in utility-modules.js I had misspelled "iluminated" instead of "illuminated".

Answer (score 1):

If this is what you're after, I think you just need to modify the way you reference the target element...

```
... document.querySelector(`#${elementId}`).classList[action](className));
```

```js
const short = [{
    elementId: "this",
    action: "add",
    className: "active"
  },
  {
    elementId: "that",
    action: "remove",
    className: "active"
  },
  {
    elementId: "other",
    action: "remove",
    className: "active"
  },
];


const addRemoveClasses = element => {
  element.forEach(({
    elementId,
    className,
    action
  }) => document.querySelector(`#${elementId}`).classList[action](className));

};
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener("click", () => addRemoveClasses(short));
```

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

.active {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id='this'>This</div>
<div id='that' class='active'>That</div>
<div id='other' class='active'>Other</div>
<button>test</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,

This works fine if all code is in one file I suppose and you do not "store" the classes anywhere. 

I have however 3 files where in one I store all the changes that are supposed to be implemented upon an action -> the const short.
Second file where I store as for now one function the myDOMelement with all the classes used in my index in const x,
and then the scrips.js file where is the main code. 

I recon the problem is that I import the const short.

Comment: I have also updated the question and added github repo if that helps.